# How to handle session to keep login information using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, session

I want to make login form with Spring MVC using Hibernate.

I found that I need to use 'session' to keep login information.

So, I use it in 'Controller.java', '.jsp'.

But It seems didn't work.

Below is my code. Controller.java:

```
@Controller
public class PassengerController {

    @Autowired
    private PassengerService passengerService;

    public void setPassengerService(PassengerService passengerService) {
        this.passengerService = passengerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String login(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {

        String id = request.getParameter("idInput");
        String pw = request.getParameter("pwInput");

        // check DB 
        // if it is right, add session.
        session.setAttribute("id", id);
        session.setAttribute("pw", pw);

        return "flightschedule";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout") 
    public String logout(HttpSession session) {
        session.invalidate();
        return "flightschedule";
    }

}
```

Below is part of flightschedule.jsp:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.loginId eq null}">
    <!-- Not login: show login button  -->
    <div class="loginArea">
        <form action="${loginAction}">     <!-- // URL '/login' -->
            <input type="text" name="idInput" placeholder="ID" class="loginInput"> 
            <input type="password" name="pwInput" placeholder="PASSWORD" class="loginInput"> 
            <input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
    </div>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${sessionScope.loginId ne null}">
    <!-- already login: show logout button -->
    <div class="loginArea">
        <form action="${logoutAction}">  <!-- // URL '/logout' -->
            <input type="button" name="idInput" id="loginInfo" value="Welcome ${sessionScope.loginId}"> 
            <input id="logoutButton" type="submit" value="LOGOUT">
        </form>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

I intended that when session.id exists, show log out button and when session.id doesn't exist, show login button.

I don't want to use interceptors or spring security etc..

I thought they're too complex to my little project.

And, I have login/logout form at all most of my pages. I don't use a separate page to login.

So I don't want to use interceptor. I just want to check whether session key exists in some jsp pages. Depending on its presence, I want to change page's view.

Above's code work partly. When login, it shows 'Welcome userId'.

But, when I click page's logo(then go to the first page), It still show 'login' button. It have to show 'log-out' button becuase session.loginId exists!

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Sorry to say, But `interceptor`is the best thing to handle this. More over its not at all complex rather just a new class itself. If you really dont want to use interceptor then use `filter`

Comment: @vipincp I see. What I saw about `interceptor` sample source, they have to redirect some page. For instance, if I try to access some page without login, LoginHandler make me redirect login page. But I don't have a separate page to login. Without login page, with just login form, is interceptor possible?

Comment: How the login form is triggered, Based on some parameter or something right? That parameter can be passed from interceptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In login method you put

```
 // check DB 
    // if it is right, add session.
    session.setAttribute("id", id);
    session.setAttribute("pw", pw);
```

but on JSP check `sessionScope.loginId` , looks like you should check attribute with name `id`.